# MenuItem text and icon are not being set

Tags: android, menu, navigation-drawer

my application provides a list of recipes 
at first all recipes are meat based and on the click of a switch in the setting page they become vegetable based
i want my app to change the titles and icons of the menu from meat based to vegetable based
i have put this code in the onPrepareOptionsMenu and it is being called but the titles are not being updated

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    final MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main_drawer, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 11) {
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
        MenuItem item1 = menu.findItem(R.id.nav_all);
        MenuItem item2 = menu.findItem(R.id.nav_beef);
        MenuItem item4 = menu.findItem(R.id.nav_chicken);
        Log.d("ISVEG", MeApplication.getIsVeg().toString());
        if (MeApplication.getIsVeg()) {
            item1.setTitle("Omlets");
            item1.setIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.eggs));
            item2.setTitle("Broccoli");
            item2.setIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.broccoli));
            item4.setTitle("Tomato");
            item4.setIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.tomato));

        } else {
            item1.setTitle("All meat");
            item1.setIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.allmeat));
            item2.setTitle("Beef");
            item2.setIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.steak));
            item4.setTitle("Chicken");
            item4.setIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.thanksgiving));
        }
    }
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `invalidateOptionsMenu();` from `onPrepareOptionsMenu`. Its not required since `onPrepareOptionsMenu` will prepare the Screen's standard options menu to be displayed. This is called right before the menu is shown, every time it is shown